# Converting a variable into a string creates EOF error

Tags: python, string, tkinter, python-2.x, eof

```
def evaluate(x):
    number = str(eval(entry_drones.get()))
    if x == drones :
        create_drone(number)
entry_drones = Entry(frame, text = "1")
entry_drones.bind("<Return>", evaluate(drones))
```

I have a program that creates an error along the lines of:

```
number = str(eval(entry_drones.get()))
File "<string>", line 0
  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I tried searching for the answer online, but they say I'm either missing a parenthesis (I've been unable to spot where it is needed) or I'm using input instead of raw_input (Neither appear to be the cause of this error, at least to my knowledge)

I posted just the code that I think is relevant to the issue, but I can provide more if needed.  Take note, I have math and Tkinter imported, as well as other things.

I used `eval` because it is the only way I know (out of limited experience) to take the input from my Entry widget and simplify it before I run it through another function.

As for drones, it lets my evaluate function know which function to pass `number` to.  I snipped out all of the other options because it is repetitive and it all leads to this function.  `entry_drones` can have basic expressions put into it such as 10 * 10 or something.  In my code I set `k = 1000` and so forth, allowing me to use letters to abbreviate.

The `entry_drones.get()` should (if I'm not mistaken) grab whatever is typed into the Entry widget whenever the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: why do you use `eval` ?

Comment: What is `drones` ? and what do you put inside `entry_drones` ?

Comment: There are people who claim that `eval()` does have some valid uses. I don't believe that they would think that this is one of them.

Comment: What does `entry_drones.get()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eval` function interprets the string you pass to it as Python code. You'll get a `SyntaxError` if anything is typed in your text entry box that isn't a valid Python expression (such as an empty string, for instance). You might get other exceptions too, if you type something that could be valid, but has other problems (for instance, calling `eval` on a random string that could be a variable name will probably raise a `NameError` since there is no such variable).

If that's the only problem, you probably just want to catch exceptions from the `eval` call and either ignore them or give an appropriate error message in your program.

Be aware too that calling `eval` on user input can be really dangerous. If a user types in something like `__import__("os").system("rm -Rf /")` your program might quietly delete the entire contents of your hard drive (don't try this!). This is obviously a much bigger deal if your program is running with more permissions on your system than the user would have by themselves (probably not likely for a GUI app, but very common for a web app), but even if you're only capable of doing things that the user could do anyway from a command prompt, it's a bad idea to use `eval` on untrusted input.

Unfortunately there isn't really a trivial way to do what I think you want (simplifying mathematical expressions, possibly including calls to functions like `math.sqrt`) without a bunch of work. One option would be to pass the string to `ast.parse` to get an abstract syntax tree, and then walk the tree to make sure it only does stuff you want to allow (such as using mathematical operators, and calling specific whitelisted functions (e.g. the ones in the `math` module). You can then pass the validated AST to `compile` and then `eval` it with confidence that it won't do anything bad.

Answer (score 2):

**`eval()` is very dangerous** as @Blckknght explained well.

On a side note, Just to point out the actual root cause of the issue , it should be because of the line -

```
entry_drones.bind("<Return>", evaluate(drones))
```

This would run the function `evalute()` when this line is executed, and that is most probably before the app has even completely started, so the entry `entry_drones` is empty causing the issue. Then if it were to run successfully, it would pass the returned value to the bind method, in this case, `None` would be returned.

I believe if you want to send a parameter to your `evaluate()` function, then you should first make it accept more than one paraemter, since `bind` itself sends it `event` parameter. Example -

```
def evaluate(event, x):
    ...
```

Then use `lambda` expression with default value to pass the `drones` into `x`. Example -

```
entry_drones.bind("<Return>", lambda event, x=drones: evaluate(event, x))
```